# Set element override width limits

Tags: css

I have a `hr` element that's **inside a div setting width to %50**.

```
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
  padding: 0;      
}
```

hr width inherits it's div parent width.

Is there a way to set the hr width to fit all the screen ommiting the width of its container?

Comment: Have you tried with `width: 200%;`?

Comment: you mean fullscreen without stretching the 50% div?

Comment: With `width:200%` it will be stretched to the full width of your DIV parent. To be fullscreen you'll need javascript.

Comment: @Ladineko yes, thats exactly what I mean.

Comment: @AdrianBer can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made set a `max-width` to the div and increase the `%` on the `HR`.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/M59YP/